# How I can configure TinyMCE HTMLFIELD to allow users to browse their file explorer/finder and upload an image or paste url

Tags: django-models, tinymce, htmlwidgets

I am working on Django app and I have downloaded `tinymce` to help me build a html widget, then I created HTMLFIELD in my model.
(as the screenshot show). it seems by default, the add image tab only has image url source to add, how I can make it give another option which to browse from file storage
Note that I am using `Django==2.2.6` and I don't want to upgrade to latest, but still want `filebrowser` to work, Thanks

[image]

```
from django.db import models
from tinymce.models import HTMLField

class Space(models.Model):
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    description = HTMLField(null=True, blank=True)
```

my approach
I have add this code into my settings.py  but it didn't work

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins': 'print preview textcolor importcss searchreplace autolink autosave save directionality visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount textpattern noneditable help charmap emoticons',
    'toolbar': 'insert | undo redo |  formatselect | bold italic backcolor forecolor  | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help',
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 10,
    'width': 'auto',
    'language': 'en',
}
TINYMCE_FILEBROWSER = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function in your views to handle to the file upload

```
import os

from django.conf import settings
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        file_obj = request.FILES['file']
        file_name_suffix = file_obj.name.split(".")[-1]
        if file_name_suffix not in ["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg", ]:
            return JsonResponse({"message": "Wrong file format"})

        path = os.path.join(
            settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
            'tinymce',
        )
        # If there is no such path, create
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)

        file_path = os.path.join(path, file_obj.name)

        file_url = f'{settings.MEDIA_URL}tinymce/{file_obj.name}'

        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            return JsonResponse({
                "message": "file already exist",
                'location': file_url
            })

        with open(file_path, 'wb+') as f:
            for chunk in file_obj.chunks():
                f.write(chunk)

        return JsonResponse({
            'message': 'Image uploaded successfully',
            'location': file_url
        })
    return JsonResponse({'detail': "Wrong request"})
```

Create a js file in your static file called tinyInject.js

```
// place this file inside of your static folder with name 'tinyInject.js'

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/u6d6drp5f5nqzvqu6eujg1dnek4vrscdre339fvjpf0ik7bw/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js"
document.head.appendChild(script);

script.onload = function(){
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML

        // For more info regarding local upload in tinymce https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/local-upload/
        images_upload_url: '/upload_image/', // Image upload address in Django route
        
        height: 456,
        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
            'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
            'table emoticons template paste help maxchars'
        ],
        toolbar: 'fullscreen | undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | ' +
            'bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | ' +
            'forecolor backcolor emoticons | uploadimage help ',    
        paste_data_images: true,
        menu: {
            favs: {title: 'My Favorites', items: 'code visualaid | searchreplace | emoticons'}
        },
        menubar: 'favs file edit view insert format tools table help',
        content_css: 'css/content.css'
    })
}
```

visit https://gist.github.com/AshishPandagre/c6a3b0f5ff4724ed5d29b4ff347828f4

This is will be a great help, or you could try django-ckeditor it is easier to implement into a project